# Can Camelot Wheel help in modulation?

Tags: harmony, modulation

I almost casually found out about the [Camelot Wheel](https://mixedinkey.com/Book/How-To-Use-Harmonic-Mixing-2):

It is about mixing, but can't the same rules be applied to find nearby keys to modulate to? Of course it would not tell all of the information, but it would help choose the easier keys to move to (assuming we stay with major/minor modes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!

Keys in the same "Camelot key code" (like 1A and 1B, 5A and 5B, etc.) are just what music theorists normally call **relative keys**, meaning the two keys share the same key signatures. For example 5B (E-flat major) has 3 flats, which is the same as C minor in 5A.

The "different but harmonically compatible keys" are what we call **closely related keys**. Closely related keys add or substract one accidental from the main key. For instance, the keys closely related to E-flat major (which has 3 flats; again, this is 5B in the wheel) are B-flat major (2 flats; 6B) and A-flat major (4 flats; 4B).

For what it's worth, this whole "Camelot Wheel" thing is just a needless reinvention of the Circle of Fifths. (It looks to me like this Mark Davis dude just wanted a reason to slap his name on something.)

Comment: The Camelot wheel and the Nashville Number System are both just rebrandings of known systems. People like to add their own flavors to well established things and call it something new.

Comment: Not only "a needless reinvention", but completely oversold. It might "guarantee that your mixes are harmonically correct" by some definition of "guarantee" and "correct", but it will also guarantee they are less exciting than kissing your grandmother, if that's the *only* way you mix keys.

Comment: @alephzero not related to mixing in my question, not an ineteresting topic, just to see if it work for modulations, but as said in the answer, is just a copy of circle of fifth :)

Comment: @Dom - what was the NNS before it became NNS?

Comment: @Tim it was Roman numeral analysis

Comment: @Dom - which, funnily enough, is how I tend to use it. A sort of bastardisation of the two systems, which I find easier to read and write.